# Manga with blue haired kid from a cursed land using a rapier

Tags: story-identification, manga

He was chased out of his village because of some curse or something. At a school practicing swordsmanship with some sort of elemental abilities. I think he was from some sort of forbidden zone where there are lots of monsters.

Comment: I forgot the title but I think it was like 3 letters or something

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: A new user with the username 'Ben Chen' has attempted to edit this question to state that the manga was in full colour. If that person is you, and you've lost access to the account you used to post this question, please merge your new account with the previous one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Doing so will enable you to edit this question without approval from others, post comments within this thread, and mark an answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if you wish.